# Running feature file with TestNG

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

When I tried to run a simple feature file with TestNG, I got an error.
Please help to resolve it. I am new to cucumber with TestNG.

My test runner file:

```
package myCucumberLearningPackage;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome=true,
        features="src/myCucumberLearningPackage",
        plugin ={"pretty" , "html:target/cucumber-html-report"}
        )

public class shoppingTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{    
}
```

Error:

```
Error parsing feature file shopping.feature
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

SKIPPED: feature
         Runs Cucumber Feature
java.lang.RuntimeException: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file shopping.feature
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:162)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:431)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1335)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1051)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1140)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
Caused by: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file shopping.feature
    at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:133)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromFeaturePath(CucumberFeature.java:104)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:54)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:235)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.getFeatures(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:85)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:93)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.features(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:136)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 12: '%_FEATURE_END_%'. See http://wiki.github.com/cucumber/gherkin/lexingerror for more information.
    at gherkin.lexer.En.scan(En.java:904)
    at gherkin.lexer.I18nLexer.scan(I18nLexer.java:36)
    at gherkin.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:62)
    at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:131)
    ... 33 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@3c5a99da: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 15 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@7dc36524: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@6debcae2: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@23223dd8: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@3cb5cdba: 0 ms
```

Comment: I got it solved and I did a mistake on feature file where I gave "scenarios" instead of "scenario"

Comment: You should close the question by anwering to you. BTW, if you want to use cucumber with testng, your are not supposed to use junit api (which is currently ignored)

Comment: please do not use "@RunWith tag" , it has no use in TestNG as pointed out by @Julien Herr , also you could look at this repo which explains how to use TestNG with cucumber.
https://github.com/igniteram/testng-cucumber